# Github action not uploading artifact

Tags: workflow, artifacts, github-actions

I'm having an issue with uploading artifacts to github from within a workflow.

This is my yaml file:

```
on:
  push:
      branches:
      - master

jobs:
    build:
      name: build and test
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v1
        - name: Install robotframework and dependencies
          run: |
            pip install selenium
            pip install robotframework
            pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
            pip install robotframework-imaplibrary
            pip install robotframework-httplibrary
            pip install robotframework-requests
        - name: Download and install chromedriver
          run: |
            wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip
            sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
            export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
        - name: Run robot tests
          run: |
            cd robot/tests
            python -m robot -i ready bookingform.robot
        - name: publish test results
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          with:
            name: report
            path: report.html
        - name: clean up stuff
          run: |
            history
            pwd
```

Everything runs fine up until "publish test results", at which point nothing is written to the logs and no artifacts are uploaded. If I view the workflow log, there is a grey icon alongside that step (not the usual check or red x), so I'm really baffled at what could be happening. I added arbitrary stuff to the "clean up stuff" step just to test what happens, and that step isn't run either.

I've tried messing around with the path, thinking that it could be related to the path being invalid or something, but that hasn't helped. No matter what I add near the bottom of that file, the same behaviour occurs.

I have tried running another workflow file which uploads artifacts and that ran fine, the logs showed that the upload action was invoked and that the artifact was saved, but I don't see anything like that when my yaml file is used.

Comment: I used `ls -la` to print the directory contents when I was having issues getting artifact uploads working. Maybe try that in the `Run robot tests` step to make sure you're working with the right directory structure?

Comment: Remember that on each step you are put back into root workflow directory; during publish step you are NOT in `robot/tests/` anymore.

Comment: Thank you @Samira, that gave me some pointers. I also realised something else; steps are skipped if there are failures, so I added an ```if: always()``` to the relevant steps and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each job step resets the working path to `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, which will be the root of your repository after `actions/checkout` runs.

The `upload-artifact` action most likely can't find `report.html` because it's no longer in the correct directory.

Try changing the path as follows:

```
        - name: publish test results
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          with:
            name: report
            path: robot/tests/report.html
```

There is also a `working-directory` that you can set for a step. However, it seems to be incompatible with `uses` for actions. It can only apply to `run` script steps.

Using `working-directory` with `uses` will *NOT* work:

```
        - name: publish test results
          working-directory: robot/tests
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          with:
            name: report
            path: report.html
```

Using `working-directory` with `run` *will* work:

```
        - name: print test results
          working-directory: robot/tests
          run: cat report.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are not executed, if previous Tasks have failed; see [Status check functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions).

Using `if: ${{ failure() }}` a Task only executes, if the previous Task has failed.

So for me it solved the Problem to add `if: ${{ failure() }}`:

```
      - name: Upload Cypress Artifacts
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: ./cypress
```